# How to get rid of a persistent clipboard error?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, clipboard

I'm really new to VBA so please be really specific with your answer.

The code I've written does a lot of copy and paste functions. Every time I run the code, I get a pop-up box telling me that I have a Clipboard error:

> We couldn't copy the content to the clipboard because it's in use by another application. You can still paste your content within this workbook, but it won't be available in other applications.

[image: Clipboard error]

I have tried `Application.CutCopyMode = False` and `Call ClearClipboard` after copying but I still get the message.

This is one of the copy code routines. It just copies the contents of one worksheet to another, in different workbooks:

```vb
For Each cell In destinationWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    cell.Value = CStr(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

And this is the other copy code routine, which does a column by column copy in different workbooks:

```vb
sourceColumn = 0
For i = 1 To sourceSheet.Cells(1, sourceSheet.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If sourceSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = sourceColumnName Then
        sourceColumn = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I don't think you need to copy each cell individually? Maybe better off copying the whole sheet, and then deleting the stuff you don't need on the new sheet.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't perform any copy/paste operations though?

Comment: Can you add the entire code to your question? Only the `Cell.Copy` and `Cell.Paste` type of methods actually use the clipboard. `Cell1.Value=Cell2.Value` style commands do not